# Adding metrics to existing model in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, metrics

I have an existing model and would like to add additional metrics to it. The [Keras metrics page](https://keras.io/metrics/) says the metrics are added at compile time, but I would like to add them after loading (in part because `model.load_model()` only seems to load the first metric, and because I have new metrics I would like to try on existing model first). Is that possible?

Comment: You can compile a model as many times as you want. That will not change it's weights. So you can load model and then compile model with metrics.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that! Care to make an answer out of it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compile a model as many times as you want. That will not change its weights.

So you can load the model and then compile it with metrics.

The only possible problem of recompiling the model is possibly resetting the optimizer state.

Comment: When you say "possibly resetting...", do you mean that you are not sure about it or that it only happens in some circumstances?

Comment: I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 9):

Just adding this gist for quick and easy copy/paste answer for your convenience:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model_path = 'path/to/your/old_model.h5'
new_metrics = [<metrics to add>...]  # for example ['binary_accuracy']

model = load_model(model_path)
model.compile(optimizer=model.optimizer,
                        loss=model.loss,
                        metrics=model.metrics+new_metrics)
```

Make sure to add needed parameters to the compile function if used any other than the above case.

Comment: This would'nt work in many cases, since metrics have to be in a dictionary to define in Multi-Task output which metric is applied.